# VBA how to remove string line in pragraph?

Tags: string, excel, vba

For example , i want to remove all string in line 10 below .
What the VBA code can be use?

1. Limitation: Quality metrics are not available
2. Limitation Cause: HTTPS connection
3. Service Bearer: Lte
4. Data Radio Bearer: LTE
5. Impairment free: Yes
6. Is Multi RAB: No
7. LTE Serving Cell Count Average: 1
8. Number Of Video Session Interruptions: 0
9. Maximum Duration Of Video Session Interruptions: 0.0 s
10. Total Duration Of Video Session Interruptions: 0.0 s
11. Clip Length: 100.704 s

Comment: How is the data organized? Do you have 11 rows and two columns? Do you want to delete entire row or just the string part? How do you choose which line to remove? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes have 11 row. Ignore that number left. I just put it. My data right. I want to remove all string at line 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach is to go to menu Developer, click "Record macro" and do the action you want to do (that is remove string in row 10). Then you click "stop recording", click "Macros", select Macro1 and click the button Edit. A new window opens with VBA code that does what you just recorded. In your case the code is

```
Sub Macro1()
  Range("A10").Select
  Selection.ClearContents
End Sub
```

This is where you start. Then you can play with the code and further adjust it to your needs.